# yii How to register the onbeforesave event model?

Tags: php, yii

Now, I have created 10+ a model, you need to filter the content before you save, how I can register the model onbeforesave event of a Public

```
protected function beforeSave()
    {
        if($this->hasEventHandler('onBeforeSave'))
        {
            $event=new CModelEvent($this);
            $this->onBeforeSave($event);
            return $event->isValid;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Comment: can you elaborate ?! I sorry but i don't really understand what you wanna say with 'of a Public' . what you mean by filter? you mean validate that user input data in that model attributes are safe to send to db? if so you should have your model rules() with the attributes, and they types set up correctly. after that you can call $model->validate() yii will check them for you based on your rules() method.

Comment: why you want to filter ? for security purpose like Xss atack prevention?

Comment: I hope to be able to have a public method that will not let me change a lot of code

Answer (score 1):

```
public function beforeSave() {
     if (!empty($this->attribute))
         // apply logic to validate content  
     return true;
 }
```

provide attribute name to which content you want to apply check.
for one beforeSave() to all model [check here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/10/how-to-automate-timestamps-in-activerecord-models/)
and [also](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/32744-where-to-add-code-that-will-execure-for-all-models/)

Comment: To do so I need to change more than 10 model documents, I view the source code, checks aware onbeforesave this event before you save the data in external register an event, without having to change the model file., I think this will reduceMy workload

Comment: check links. you will get what you want to do.

Comment: This implementation has a bug: you **must** always call `parent::beforeSave()`